# Cucumber: Type Mismatch cannot covert from Class <Step Definition> to Class<?extends Runner> in eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber, maven

I have been playing around with Selenium Cucumber and came across this error message:

Type mismatch: Cannot convert from Class StepDefinition to Class?extends Runner

and here is my code:

```
package com.cucumber.JUnit;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.cucumber.steps.StepDefinition;

@RunWith(StepDefinition.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  format = { "pretty", "html:report/test-report" },
  features = { "src/test/resources/sample.feature" },
  glue = { "com.cucumber.steps.StepDefinition" }
)

public class SampleCucumberJUnitRunner {
  //Note: As with all Cucumber tests, the .feature file(s) will define what 
will actually run.
}
```

Unable to understand the source of error even though I have imported the class correctly. Am I missing something???

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: **Getting this error -** Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Cucumber> to Class<? extends Runner> **Below is my code -** package StepDefinitions; import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions; @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/Features", glue = {"StepDefinitions"})
public class TestRunner { } @Someone can help me in this error?

Answer (score 1):

Change `@RunWith(StepDefinition.class)` to `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`.

The Cucumber runner needs to run with a class that extends Runner.class; StepDefinition.class does not extends Runner.class.

Comment: Does this answer your question, or do you need something else?